# angular flex layout wrap items grow and shrink

Tags: flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have a layout container that shows items like this:

[image]

My code:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="50">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" fxFlex="1 3 30" *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category.DISPLAY | translate}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the row to wrap the items based off the space available. In this case, I would like the "Email" category to take up the entire space of the newly wrapped row. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

simple example

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
      <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" fxFlex="3 0 33.3" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">aaaaaaaaa</button>
  </div>
```